# Django. Realizar query set y mostrar resultados en la misma página.

Tags: django, formularios

es un gusto estar aquí.

Primero cabe denotar que soy muy nuevo en Django. Poseo una duda. Es posible una forma en que pueda realizar un query set, buscando un elemento de la base de datos y mostrándolo en la misma página. Y de ser así, como sería claro está.

Pues hasta donde sé. La vista genérica necesita un template diferente para mostrar los resultados de una petición realizada a través de la vista.

La intención es realizar una sección de búsqueda del personal registrado en el software.

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Hola, es necesario que postees codigo que al menos hayas intentado realizar de modo que podamos ayudarte, eso dara mas contexto a la pregunta. Aqui te anexo la guia de como preguntar en Stack : https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si amigo si se puede hacer lo que deseas (: puedes hacerlo con ajax o más facil con **django-filter** que sirve para filtrar por nombre, fechas, numeros, etc. Todo esto en una misma plantilla. Un abrazo!